# onSaveInstanceState() should be in onDestroy() rather than onStop()?

Tags: android

Why does the system call onSaveInstanceState() when the activity enters the stop state?

**Since the activity's instance s kept resident in memory when it is stopped**, and its current state is lost only when the activity is destroyed.

So the system should rather call the onSaveInstanceState() before entering or inside **onDestroy() rather than onStop()**.

Isn't it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called (generally, only if you `finish()` your activity) and because after `onStop()`, your activity is not guaranteed to remain.  It might be destroyed for any number of reasons once it is not the foreground activity.

I always assume that after `onPause()`, the next callback to be made **might** be `onCreate()`, that way, I never get surprised ;)

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me another thing?

I have read that in citical situations, the process might be killed after onPause(). So should/can we save the instance state by implementing onSaveInstanceState() in onPause() as well?

Comment: Do you mean the Activity state, or your state (data)? The Activity state is taken care of for you. You only need to modify it if you're doing some special stuff. Your state should be saved, e.g. SharedPreferences or SQLite, in onPause() and reloaded in onResume().

Answer (score 3):

`onSaveInstanceState` saves the view state of the Fragment/Activity as well as custom instance data.  The view objects can and will be destroyed after `onStop`, so `onSaveInstanceState` must be called to preserve their state.

This is discussed in [the docs for `Activity.onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29):

> The default implementation takes care of most of the UI per-instance state for you by calling `onSaveInstanceState()` on each view in the hierarchy that has an id, and by saving the id of the currently focused view (all of which is restored by the default implementation of `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`. If you override this method to save additional information not captured by each individual view, you will likely want to call through to the default implementation, otherwise be prepared to save all of the state of each view yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To save additional data about the activity state, you must override the onSaveInstanceState() callback method. The system calls this method when the user is leaving your activity and passes it the Bundle object that will be saved in the event that your activity is destroyed unexpectedly. If the system must recreate the activity instance later, it passes the same Bundle object to both the onRestoreInstanceState() and onCreate() methods.